# compare values from multidimensional array and add key to array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [681074CRPAK4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681074
            [1] => 681074CRPAK4
            [2] => 5602385431605
        )

    [681520XXXP6L] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681520
            [1] => 681520XXXP6L
            [2] => 5602385667394
        )

    [681530XXXP6V] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6V
            [2] => 5602385667417
        )

    [681530XXXP6W] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6W
            [2] => 5602385667424
        )
    [681530XXXP6X] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6X
            [2] => 5602385667400
        )   
    )
```

I want to compare the value of `key[0]` of each array.

If they are the same then I would like to add a new `key[3]` to each array with an id.

This is an array of variable products if the product has the same `key[0]` then its the same product with different variations.

If the `key[0]` is different from the previous then add `id+1`, in this example, I would like to end up with:

```
Array
(
    [681074CRPAK4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681074
            [1] => 681074CRPAK4
            [2] => 5602385431605
            [3] => 1
        )

    [681520XXXP6L] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681520
            [1] => 681520XXXP6L
            [2] => 5602385667394
            [3] => 2
        )

    [681530XXXP6V] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6V
            [2] => 5602385667417
            [3] => 3
        )

    [681530XXXP6W] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6W
            [2] => 5602385667424
            [3] => 3
        )
    [681530XXXP6X] => Array
        (
            [0] => 681530
            [1] => 681530XXXP6X
            [2] => 5602385667400
            [3] => 3
        )   

)
```

can you guys help me with this?

I tried this: 
but does not work

```
foreach ($new as $current_key => $current_array) {

            foreach ($new as $search_key => $search_array) {

                    $ref1 = $current_array[0];      
                    $ref2 = $search_array[0];       

                if (($search_key != $current_key) and ($ref1 == $ref2)) {

                    $current_array[3] = $p_id_product;

                }
                else{
                    $current_array[3] = $p_id_product++;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Help? Yes, probably. Do it all for you? No. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you taking this information from a SQL database?

Comment: @arcanine from webservice

Comment: @PatrickQ i placed the code i tried above.

Comment: What does the extra key/value buy you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already sorted the array by the initial index, so at least they are grouped:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        'foo',
        'spam',
        'bar',
    ],
    [
        'foo',
        'eggs',
    ],
    [
        'bar',
        'ham'
    ],
];

$output  = [];
$counter = 0;
$last    = null;
foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    if($last !== $v[0])
        $counter++;

    $v[3]       = $counter;
    $output[$k] = $v;
    $last       = $v[0];
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'spam',
    2 => 'bar',
    3 => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'eggs',
    3 => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'bar',
    1 => 'ham',
    3 => 2,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that's it.